# calculate the influence of one observation on overall result in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table, apply, purrr

I have a overview table - list of item count, the actual cost and the predicted cost

```
myData <- data.table("itemCount" = c(3000, 20, 50, 9),
                     "cost" = c(120, 118, 165, 93), 
                     "prediction" = c(120, 100, 150, 120))
```

Then I calculate the individual and overall profit:

```
myData[, "profit" := cost/prediction]

total <- myData[, .(itemsTotal = sum(itemCount),
                costTotal  = sum(cost), 
                predictionTotal = sum(prediction))][
                  , "profit" := costTotal/predictionTotal 
                ]
```

Now, for every row, I want to calculate what the overall profit would have been if that particular row was excluded from the analysis. For Example if row two was missing:

```
myData$diffinProfit <- NA
      myDataEx <- myData[- 2, ]
      totalEx <- myDataEx[, .(itemsTotal = sum(itemCount),
                              costTotal  = sum(cost), 
                              predictionTotal = sum(prediction))][
                                , "profit" := costTotal/predictionTotal
```

so I wrote a for loop to do this

```
myData$diffinProfit <- NA
for(observation in seq_along(length(myData)-1)){
  
  myDataEx <- myData[- observation, ]
  totalEx <- myDataEx[, .(itemsTotal = sum(itemCount),
                          costTotal  = sum(cost), 
                          predictionTotal = sum(prediction))][
                            , "profit" := costTotal/predictionTotal 
                            ]
  
  myData$diffinProfit[[observation]] <- totalEx$profit
  
}
```

However, I only get result for the first observation. How can I find the for loop? Its there any way I could use an apply function? I was considering mapply? or maybe a purrr function?

Comment: First, `length(myData)` is the number of columns, not the number of rows.

Comment: For profit, you divided cost and prediction. If the cost is $118, and the prediction is $100, that's not $1.18, nor is it 118%.  Profit is $18 or just over 15%. I could be way off, because I don't know what your numbers actually represent. If the cost is 118 for each of the 20, the number is even further off. If you want the literal value, subtract. If you want percentage, you need `1 - (prediction/cost)`

Comment: well actually I am calculating the loss ratio, the column name is misleading I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is that `length(myData)` is reporting the number of columns, not the number of rows. But I think we can do without the `for` loop (though `sapply` is similar to it in deeper code).

```r
myData[, otherProfit := sapply(seq_len(.N), function(z) sum(cost[-z])/sum(prediction[-z]))]
myData
#    itemCount  cost prediction profit otherProfit
#        <num> <num>      <num>  <num>       <num>
# 1:      3000   120        120  1.000   1.0162162
# 2:        20   118        100  1.180   0.9692308
# 3:        50   165        150  1.100   0.9735294
# 4:         9    93        120  0.775   1.0891892
```

Although mathematically, it's possible to do it without a loop at all:

```r
sumcost <- sum(myData$cost)
sumpred <- sum(myData$prediction)
myData[, profit2 := (sumcost-cost)/(sumpred-prediction)]
myData
#    itemCount  cost prediction profit otherProfit   profit2
#        <num> <num>      <num>  <num>       <num>     <num>
# 1:      3000   120        120  1.000   1.0162162 1.0162162
# 2:        20   118        100  1.180   0.9692308 0.9692308
# 3:        50   165        150  1.100   0.9735294 0.9735294
# 4:         9    93        120  0.775   1.0891892 1.0891892
```

I'm not going to benchmark 4 rows, but I'd be surprised if this second "vectorized" approach isn't more efficient than the `sapply` above or a `for`-loop alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of row ids and the data.table native `.GRP` group counter

```
library(data.table)

myData <- data.table("itemCount" = c(3000, 20, 50, 9),
                     "cost" = c(120, 118, 165, 93), 
                     "prediction" = c(120, 100, 150, 120))

myData[, "profit" := cost/prediction]

# assign row ids
myData[, ID := .I]

# loop over each row and take all values that are not in the current row
# .GRP is a group identifier and since you loop over all rows, there are as many groups as rows
myData[, total_profit_excl := myData[ID != .GRP, sum(cost) / sum(prediction)],
       by = ID]
myData
#>    itemCount cost prediction profit ID total_profit_excl
#> 1:      3000  120        120  1.000  1         1.0162162
#> 2:        20  118        100  1.180  2         0.9692308
#> 3:        50  165        150  1.100  3         0.9735294
#> 4:         9   93        120  0.775  4         1.0891892
```